# Alert accessibility development for visually impaired users Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility

In my page I show an alert using Javascript, but I am facing a focus problem, the focus is always on the main form, so a visually impaired user can't use the accessibility tool to read the error msg as it is reading the main form not the error msg in the js alert. So what I am trying to do is to make the focus on the alert so the accessibility tool can read the error message for the user.

My code:

```
alert('Errors\n' + msg + '\n\n' + msg)
```

I tried focus and slidedown and it is not working

```
$("#jquery_validate_error_focus").focus();
$("#jquery_validate_error").slideDown();
```

Comment: If you don't get a fix for the alert itself, you could switch to using a box or banner on the main page for showing the error.

Comment: When you say JS alert, what do you mean? From the JS code it looks like the `window.alert` function, but how would you focus that using a jQuery selector? Do you have another element on the page that also outputs the error message?

Comment: I meant calling the alert function and no there are no there elements, all the error msgs are combined to be shown in that one alert

Comment: I would highly recommend making your own modal that you can style, rather than using the native alert.  Other than being able to style it, it's not the '90s anymore.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks but what kind of model are you talking about?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/  https://jqueryui.com/dialog/  A modal/dialog is effectively the same thing.  It's an element that you position on your page with a z-index higher than the other content, so it shows on top of the other conent, which acts like a native alert in that you can show important information quickly.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#alert and https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#alertdialog can be used in conjunction with them to help screen readers use them appropriately.

Comment: Please post this as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually using the `alert()` function, you don’t have an issue, because it’s a very accessible, interrupting dialog component that will receive focus as well.

If you are injecting/showing the error message in the page, you can fix the focus and announcement issue by means of the [ARIA `alert` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#alert).

```html
<div role="alert">Your name is required</div>
```

It will make the screenreader announce the feedback wherever focus or reading position is.

But you also need to keep that feedback message visually close to where the user interacts with the form. Visually impaired users also use screen magnifiers and might see but a field or button at a time.

See also [Usable and Accessible Form Validation and Error Recovery by WebAIM](https://webaim.org/techniques/formvalidation/)